# How can I close a gap in a bar chart?

Tags: plotting, charts

I have the bar chart below:

[image]

My code:

```
BarChart[{Labeled[{a760, c760, b760, d760}, "760" ], 
  Labeled[{a780, c780, b780, d780}, "780" ]}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green, Black}, 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[{"65.5 ps", "274 ps", "16.8 ps", "2040 ps" }, {Right}], 
 BarSpacing -> {0, 1}]
```

The third entry of 780 is missing, so I used `Missing[]`. I want to attach the forth entry

of 780 to the second entry of 780. The point is that the color of the forth entry must

remain black because each color indicates a quality such as lifetimes.

Comment: When you say "attach" do you mean "stack"? That is, to put the black bar on top of the red bar? Or below? Or what does attach mean in this case?

Comment: I mean put the dark one alongside of the red one. I want them side to side.

Comment: Please include the data, if possible so we can reproduce your graph and inspect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any clever way to remove the gap, so here is a way to get the chart using `Style` to specify individual colours for the bars:

```
data1 = {10, 5, 20, 2};
data2 = {12, 8, Missing[], 3};

colors = {Blue, Red, Green, Black};

applycolors = Style @@@ DeleteCases[Thread @ {#, colors}, {Missing[], _}] &;

BarChart[{
   Labeled[applycolors @ data1, "760"],
   Labeled[applycolors @ data2, "780"]},
  BarSpacing -> {0, 1}] ~Legended~
 SwatchLegend[colors, {"65.5 ps", "274 ps", "16.8 ps", "2040 ps"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the data to associate with each data point the number of `Missing[]` data to the left of that point as metadata, and using the metadata information to translate the rectangles to the left by an appropriate amount:

```
ClearAll[processF, ceF]
prepF = Function[{d}, MapIndexed[# -> Count[d[[;; #2[[1]]]], _Missing] &, d]];
ceF = Module[{box = {#[[1]] - #3[[1]], #[[2]]}},
        ChartElementDataFunction["Rectangle"][box, ##2]] &;
```

**Examples:**

Simon's example:

```
data1 = {10, 5, 20, 2};
data2 = {12, 8, Missing[], 3};
colors = {Blue, Red, Green, Black};
newdata = prepF /@ {data1, data2};
bc1 = BarChart[newdata, ChartStyle -> colors, ImageSize -> 400, BarSpacing-> {0, 1}];
bc2 = BarChart[newdata, ChartStyle -> colors, ImageSize -> 400, BarSpacing-> {0, 1},  
   ChartElementFunction -> ceF];
Column[{bc1, bc2}]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
data1 = {10, 5, Missing[], 20, 2, Missing[], 4, 5};
data2 = {12, 8, Missing[], Missing[], 3, 4, Missing[], 5};

newdata = prepF /@ {data1, data2};

bc1 = BarChart[newdata, ChartStyle -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, BarSpacing-> {0, 1}];
bc2 = BarChart[newdata, ChartStyle -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, BarSpacing-> {0, 1},
  ChartElementFunction -> ceF];

Column[{bc1, bc2}]
```

[image]